# How to avoid concordion tests to be executed multiple times when using concordion:run in html

Tags: junit, concordion

As the title states: How to avoid concordion tests to be executed multiple times when using concordion:run in html.

When you use concordion:run in your links, nice markups appear in the report.
However, adding the concordion:run attribute to your html page also triggers another test execution next to the test execution triggered from the fixture.
The latter is ofcourse very undesirable.
How can I fix this.

Env:
junit 4.8.1
concordion 1.4.4
concordion extensions 1.1.1 (not in use yet)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Concordion specification (html page) that contains links (with concordion:run) to all of the Concordion specifications that you wish to be executed. Then execute only the single fixture class related to this specification.

We tend to structure our Concordion specifications hierarchically, with a top level index page that links to a page for each theme. Each theme page then links to a page for each feature etc. We can then choose to run all of the tests by executing the top level fixture, or just the tests for a theme/feature etc, by running the corresponding fixture class.

It gets slightly more tricky if you want to have the same specification linked to from multiple specifications. Let me know if you're trying to do this - I do have some code to handle this.

Comment: Hi Nigel,
Sorry it took a while to respond.
I had chosen the alternative: not using concordion:run in the html.
Reason, the fixture classes are automatically executed by junit...